# Class instance variable not getting initialized (dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to assign values to my list but when I print the length of the list after assigning it is giving me zero even though it has one value. I'm not sure what is wrong. Here is the code:

```
// models
import '../models/models.dart';

class EventsProvider {
  // list of events
  final List<Event> _events = [
    Event(day: DateTime(2021, 9, 15), title: 'hello'),
  ];

  // method to get an event of a specific date
  List<Event> getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
    print(_events.length);
    return _events.where((event) => event.day == day).toList();
  }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

I have no idea what's wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I was using default Provider, but now I'm using the ChangeNotiferProvider and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it is working fine:

```
void main() {
  EventsProvider().getEventsForDay(DateTime(2021, 9, 15));

//Check the return value of the getEventForDay() function
  for(final event in provider){
    print(event.day);
  }
}


class EventsProvider {
  // list of events
  final List<Event> _events = [
    Event(day: DateTime(2021, 9, 15), title: 'hello'),
  ];

  // method to get an event of a specific date
  List<Event> getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
    print(_events.length);
    return _events.where((event) => event.day == day).toList();
  }
}


class Event{
  final DateTime? day;
  final String? title;
  
  const Event({this.day, this.title});
}
```

Don't forget the getEventForDay function on returns a list of event satisfying the condition you have there.